# C# using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Add new SERIES With range from other WorkSheet

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I want the Excel to look like that:

[image]

[image]

I have to try to create a workbook and Worksheets than add a chart and get a range from another chart 
for the next step I want to show multiple graphs of lines that looks this that in one chart
But for now, I just don't know how to do this

this is my code and what I have tried:

But I have got an error as

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC'
```

I have tried other ways but in all the cases I got this error...
I did not find any example of that..
And I think In random tries I will never get the right way to do that...

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace EXCELTEST
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
            xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
            {
                DisplayAlerts = true,
                Visible = true
            };
            Workbook reportWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
            Worksheet reportWorksheet = reportWorkbook.Worksheets.Add();

            reportWorksheet.Cells[1, "B"] = "Volt";
            reportWorksheet.Cells[1, "A"] = "Capacity";

            int c = 0;
            int i = 2;
            double v = 2.5;
            double vDiff = 0.050;
            while ( i < 30 )
            {

                reportWorksheet.Cells[i, "B"] = v;
                reportWorksheet.Cells[i, "A"] = c;

                v += vDiff;
                vDiff -= 0.001;
                c += 10;
                i++;
            }

            Worksheet ChartWorksheet = reportWorkbook.Worksheets.Add();
            Range chartRange;
            ChartObjects xlCharts = (ChartObjects)ChartWorksheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
            ChartObject myChart = (ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 250);
            Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
            chartRange = ChartWorksheet.get_Range("'Sheet2'!A1", "'Sheet2'!B29");
            chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange);
            //chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlLine;
            chartPage.ChartType = XlChartType.xlLine;


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using this

> `chartRange = ChartWorksheet.get_Range("'Sheet2'!A1", "'Sheet2'!B29");`

Use the below code to select the range

```
chartRange = reportWorksheet.get_Range("A1","B39");
```

and you should be getting it working..

### Edit

To get the Volt on side, try following:

```
Worksheet ChartWorksheet = reportWorkbook.Worksheets.Add();
ChartWorksheet = reportWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
ChartObjects xlCharts = (ChartObjects)ChartWorksheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
ChartObject myChart = (ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 250);
Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
SeriesCollection oSeriesCollection = (SeriesCollection)myChart.Chart.SeriesCollection();
Series Data = oSeriesCollection.NewSeries();
Data.XValues = reportWorksheet.get_Range("A2", "A29");
Data.Values = reportWorksheet.get_Range("B2", "B29");
Data.Name = "Volt";
chartPage.ChartType = XlChartType.xlLineMarkers;
```

The rendered output:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I just want the opposite..   

The Volt to be on the side and the capacity to be down..

I cant change sheet2 WorkSheet

Comment: Just one more thing!
How can I use it for multiple Series with difference Volt and difference Capacity?
To open a new question for that?

Comment: Good going @Amit, take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get to know more about [S.O](https://stackoverflow.com/help)